# Sketch: Resizing an icon button symbol moves elements when resized - as only the first element seems to adopt the pin-to-corner resizing attribute

Tags: sketch-app

Sketch42

I have a symbol button with an icon (fontawesome) and a label.

Both icon and label are set to pin-to-corner, but on resizing button instances only the first element(the icon) is fixed, whilst the second element (the label) floats.

I want both to pin-to-corner. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried grouping them and then pinning the group?

Comment: I have. Oddly the pin-to-corner then fails on the whole group - it feels like a bug

Comment: Have you tried converting the icon font to outlines? Resizing+fonts seems to be a real issue in Sketch.

Comment: The issue is not the fact the first element is an icon. In my example the first element DOES pick up on the pin-to-corner attribute (no mater if its a font or icon or outline). It's subsequent elements (in this case just text) that do not. i.e. you stretch the instance and the second element floats..

Comment: "Pin to corner" only pins to the nearest corner of each element. Most probably your text element is closer to the right corner and it pins there.

Comment: found a specific plugin for this issue which solves it perfectly: https://github.com/herrkris/sketch-dynamic-symbol-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter in the symbol select every element and set pin to corner.

Or you can use this plugin https://animaapp.github.io/Auto-Layout/

Comment: Hello Stefano. Thanks for your answer and welcome to GDSE. Could you please tell us a bit more about the plugin you're linking to and explain how it answers the question? That way, your answer retains its value in case the link breaks at a later time and it makes it look less like spam. We have had a severe uptick in spam lately and the community cracks down *hard* on any post looking like it. Thanks! If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy!

Comment: This ain't spam - it's a superb solution. Many thanks @Stefano that's a must have plugin!

Comment: @Vincent sorry :(

Comment: No need to be! Just trying to warn you that this style of post could easily be mistaken for spam. A bit more explanation undoes that very quickly :) @OTruckle Good to know! :D